# HTTP/2 HEADERS and DATA Frames

Tags: http, http2

I am trying to understand HTTP/2 in detail. I read this article about streams, messages and frames: https://hpbn.co/http2/#streams-messages-and-frames. I don't know if I got the concept right.

I came to the following conclusion:

- A message is a combination of a HEADER frame and one or more DATA
  frames.
- A DATA frame can ONLY be sent with an HEADERS frame, because I don't see any indicators which shows the DATA frames Stream ID (RFC 7540, 6.1)

  - If this is true, A DATA Frame can only be sent within a message
- A Stream can be chunked into many Frames, while it can be related to a Stream by its Stream ID

Furthermore: How is a message represented in the specification?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You got a few things incorrectly.

A *message* is a combination of one or two `HEADER` frames (carrying the HTTP headers), *zero or more* DATA frames, and *one* optional terminal `HEADER` frame (carrying the HTTP trailers).
You can look at examples in [this section of RFC 7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.3).
There is a special case for `100 Continue` responses, that can begin with two `HEADERS` rather than one. In what follows we can ignore this case.

A `DATA` frame *does* have a stream ID, because all frames share the frame header defined in [this section of RFC 7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-4.1).
What is described in section 6.1 is only the body of the `DATA` frame.

A *message* is a half of a HTTP/2 stream. A message represents either a HTTP request or a HTTP response.

A HTTP/2 stream is the combination of a request message and a response message.
Note that this is not to be confused with the `flag_end_stream` that signals the last frame sent for that particular stream by either peer.

A typical `GET` request performed by a browser will then have (assuming the stream ID is 13):

- one `HEADERS` frame with ID=13, `flag_end_headers=true` and `flag_end_stream=true` (a `GET` request typically has no body)

A typical response to that `GET` request will then have:

- one `HEADERS` frame with ID=13 and `flag_end_headers=true`
- one or more `DATA` frames, all with ID=13; the last `DATA` frame will have `flag_end_stream=true`.

Note that due to multiplexing, frames can interleave; this means that if you have two concurrent responses (say for stream 13 and stream 15), for example, you can have this sequence:

`HEADERS(13) HEADERS(15) DATA(15) DATA(13) DATA(13] DATA(15) DATA(15]`

where the bracket `]` means that it's the last frame in the stream.

Comment: I analysed your response, know I understand the concept! Can't thank you enough! Cheers!

Comment: Just to add, if the entire header block does not fit in a single HEADERS frame, the rest of the header block can be sent in CONTINUATION frames. But in such a case, all the CONTINUATION frames for a given stream ID have to be sent one after the other. 

If a HEADERS frame that is not complete is followed by a frame with a different stream ID, it would result in a connection error (RFC 7450 section 6.2).

Answer (score 2):

A supplement:

> A DATA frame can ONLY be sent with an HEADERS frame

Not true. DATA frames can also be sent with [PUSH_PROMISE](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#PUSH_PROMISE).

> I don't see any indicators which shows the DATA frames Stream ID (RFC 7540, 6.1)

That's because section 6.1 shows the **Payload** of a frame, which does not include the header part. [4.1](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#FrameHeader) tells you what the 9 bytes header looks like:

[image]

Comment: So the Payload DATA frames from 6.1 is inside the Frame Payload of 4.1?