# multiple stream with single TCP connection in http2

Tags: concurrency, stream, http2, parallels

I read and know that HTTP2 will have a single TCP connection with each client. Multiple streams can be active on a single TCP connection.
However, are the Streams sending and receiving data concurrent or parallel?

If it is concurrent, it is similar to switch context of OS. Streams will take turns sending or receiving each Frame.

If it is parallel, streams can simultaneously send or receive data.

I think it's concurrent, but I'm not sure. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The proper term to use is that HTTP/2 multiplexed streams are *interleaved*, which is the equivalent of what you describe as "concurrent" in your question.

You can see an example of interleaving in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460062/http-2-headers-and-data-frames/44466519#44466519).

Note that what you describe as "parallel" is not possible, as typically you have just one reader thread at a time from one TCP socket.

You can have parallelism if each thread reads in parallel from its own TCP sockets and you have many TCP sockets, but with just one TCP socket the reads are sequential, and once you parse the bytes that you have read, the HTTP/2 frames are interleaved.

One last correction is that HTTP/2 does not mandate that clients open only one TCP connection to the server.
This is an implementation detail.
Browser vendors have decided to open only one, but other HTTP/2 client libraries, especially when used for load testing, allow to open more than one TCP connection to the server, and typically pool these connections to reuse them.

Comment: "Browser vendors have decided to open only one" slight nit on this as it's not strictly true. Browsers do open separate connections to the same origin for credentialed/non-credentialed connections. See here for more details: https://jakearchibald.com/2017/h2-push-tougher-than-i-thought/#requests-without-credentials-use-a-separate-connection - though as that post suggests maybe they shouldn't have to?